# Hardware shopping: Which M.2 SSD should I buy?

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata

Based on this topic's answers

https://superuser.com/questions/1535127/hardware-shopping-can-all-m-key-slot-work-with-nvme#1535127

I am pretty sure that my Laptop do not accepts M.2 NVMe SSD.

I want to install an 1TB M.2 Sata III SSD,
Which one do you suggest to buy?

I can spend around R$ 800,00 (brazilian).

Comment: Any specific requirements apart from the price? I'd probably go with a Crucial MX500. It does not have any major flaws, and at least in my region, it is one of the cheapest options.

Comment: @MechEng I want 1TB space.  M.2 Sata

Comment: @K7AAY I am sorry. I do not know what is MMC/eMMC. However I know people who have installed SSD SATA on this same model.

Comment: I have two laptops with eMMC sockets which won't accept an M.2 SSD, so I'm suggesting you double-check. Are you able to find by reviewing http://samsung.com/br/support/model/NP500R5H-XD3BR if that M.2 slot is for a SATA SSD or for eMMC? Big difference, would hate for you to buy and get disappointed. Explained in http://windowscentral.com/emmc-vs-ssd and http://partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/emmc-vs-ssd-005.html